# Ruby: need to define multiple methods and call one at random

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to define a bunch of methods and then call one of them to run at random. Example:

```
def method1
   #do stuff
end

def method2
   #do stuff
end

def method3
   #do stuff
end

methodarray = [method1, method2, method3]
randomSelect = methodarray[rand(methodarray.length)]
randomSelect
```

The problem is that when the array definition step comes, it just runs all 3 methods and then empties the array. I've done some tests to know that my random selection of items in the array works (I use it in other scripts) but I've never done it using method names - always just quoted text. What am I missing?

Comment: What about `methodarray.sample`?

Comment: Instead of methods, define a bunch of lambdas. Will be much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) an array of symbols and use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-send) to call the method:

```
methods = [:method1, :method2, :method3]
send(methods.sample)
```

Comment: `send`? I'd recommend `public_send` if using `send` at all :)

Comment: `[method1, method2, method3]; methods.sample` would call all methods and return a random return value. But the OP wants to only call one randomly selected method. Regarding `send` and `public_send`: Sure might be better - depends on the context and use case.